# Why may StaticMeshComponent not move around in UnrealEngine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I use the Character C++ class to move the character in my game via AddInputMovement().

However, it only moves if there's no MeshComponent attached to it. If I attach StaticMeshComponent, it stops reacting to any keys and moving, while if I attach a common MeshComponent, it requires a **Skeletal** mesh in Blueprint Editor, although my spaceship .fbx model is not one.

What should I do? What are the reasons a StaticMesh might refuse to move?

```
ASpaceship::ASpaceship()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // !!! These lines prevent the character from moving for some reason...
    MeshComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("MeshComponent"));
    RootComponent = MeshComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Mesh Components (`UStaticMeshComponent`), just like any other component inheriting from `USceneComponent`, can and do move, if their [`Mobility`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/Mobility/) property is set to "Moveable" ([`EComponentMobility::Type::Moveable`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/EComponentMobility__Type/)).

To make sure the mesh component you added to the actor will move together with your actor, you need to make sure of several things:

1. It is set to moveable: `YourMeshComponent->Mobility = EComponentMobility::Movable;`
2. It is attached to the actor's root component: `YourMeshComponent->AttachToComponent(YourActor->GetRootComponent(), FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale);`.

Note: in the code, replace `YourActor` is your actor and `YourMeshComponent` is your mesh.

Now, any changes to your actor's transform will be applied to the mesh.